# Int array throw an exception in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Why this code is throw an exception?

```
 int n = 10;
 int[] arr = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
       arr[i] = i * 2;
 }
```

Any one can help?

Comment: You declare an array which is `null` and then you are trying to modify its elements.

Comment: your array is null, you can't loop through nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `init` your array first `int[] arr = new int[n];`

```
            int n = 10;
            int[] arr = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = i * 2;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize an array. This also has to be a fixed size, you cannot expand the lend of an array like you can with a List

you could do:

```
int n = 10;
int[] arr = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr[i] = i * 2;
}
```

This will initialise an array of length 10 then populate numbers. 
Or with a list:

```
int n = 10;
List<int> arr = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr.Add(i * 2);
}
```

Notice we do not define the length of the list like we do for the array. We then go on and add elements as we want rather than a maximum of n.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a new array with defined values instead of null. Like the code below. :).

```
int n = 10;
 int[] arr = new int[n];
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
       arr[i] = i * 2;
 }
```